# Number of $n$-bead binary necklaces [OEIS-A000013]

Tags: combinatorics, oeis, necklace-and-bracelets

I tried to obtain the number of $n$-bead binary necklaces from my program written in C++. Then, one formula came up when I looked up the number to see if my thought is correct.

> Number of $n$-bead binary necklaces with beads of $2$ colors where the colors may be swapped but turning over is not allowed
>
> $$a(n)=\sum_{d|n}\frac{\phi(2d) \, 2^\frac{n}{d}}{2n}$$ for $n>0$.

<sub>Source: [A000013](https://oeis.org/A000013)</sub>

However, although I see the number I obtained from my program was correct, I could not grasp why the formula holds.
Thus, I would appreciate it if someone could explain its derivation to me.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. To get help here, please [edit] the question to tell us what parts  of the formula you are comfortable with and what parts you can't grasp. Explaining the whole argument that leads to the formula is more than we can do here. You can start at wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. First of all, I will try to search the formula in Wikipedia.

Comment: @EthanBolker I searched "Necklace" in Wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_polynomial). Then, I saw a similar formula. However, I could not see some hints to link with the formula I had shown.

Comment: Your $a\left(n\right)$ is the number of orbits of an action of $C_2 \times C_n$ on $\left\{0,1\right\}^n$, where the $C_m$ are cyclic groups, and where the first $C_2$ acts on each entry of the $n$-tuple (turning $0$ into $1$ and vice versa) while the second $C_n$ rotates the whole $n$-tuple. [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) gives a formula for such a number of orbits. It will be a sum over elements of $C_2 \times C_n$, so you'll have to work a bit to turn it into a sum over divisors of $n$, but it shouldn't be far away.

Comment: Note: $\phi\left(2d\right)$ equals $\phi\left(d\right)$ when $d$ is odd, and equals $2\phi\left(d\right)$ when $d$ is even. This is useful in deriving the formula from Burnside's lemma.

Comment: @darijgrinberg It seems to be helpful to prove that the number in question counts also "the number of $2n$-bead balanced binary necklaces that are equivalent to their complements". Do you have any idea how to approach such a proof?

Comment: @user: I don't see an immediate bijection. But I can easily imagine proving it by Burnside, as the original question. Care to open a new question for a bijective proof?

Comment: See there for a strategy to the derivation of the formulas https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3254638/276986

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you for your reply. Now, I'm trying to prove the formula I showed. I'll let you know if I have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested in a comment, the [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) is possibly the simplest way to deal with similar problems, since you are in fact looking for the number of orbits of an action of $\Pi_n\times\Sigma_2$ on $A_n=\{0,1\}^n$, with $\pi$ and $\sigma$ being rotation and inversion operators:
$$
(\pi a)_k=a_{(k+1)\bmod n},\quad (\sigma a)_k=1-a_k,\quad  k=0\dots n. 
$$

There are altogether $2n$ elements in this action group with general form $\pi^i\sigma^j$ ($i=0\dots n-1;\ j=0,1)$, the element $\pi^0\sigma^0$ being the identity. It remains to find the number of the elements of $A_n$ fixed by each of the $2n$ operations.

The elements fixed by the rotation $\pi^j$ are well known. One can imagine that a necklace is a train consisting of $n/(n,j)$ *identical* railcars with length $(n,j)$. Clearly the necklace coincides with itself by any rotation $\pi^{k(n,j)}$, particularly by $\pi^j$ and $\pi^n=\pi^0$. As the content of a railcar can be arbitrary the number of fixed elements is $2^{(n,j)}$ for binary necklaces. If the number of railcars $n/(n,j)$ is odd this is the end of story as $\sigma$ cannot come in the game. This changes however if the number is even. In this case the number of fixed elements is doubled since the trains consisting both of *identical* as well as of *alternating "inverted"* cars are the fixed elements. It is important to observe that the number $j/(n,j)$ (the number of cars staying between $0$ and $j$) is  always odd in the considered case.

Thus we have by Burnside's lemma for the number of orbits $N$:
$$\begin{align}
N(n)&=\frac1{2n}\left[\sum_{1\le i\le n}^{n/(n,i)=0\bmod 2}2^{(n,i)+1}
+\sum_{1\le i\le n}^{n/(n,i)=1\bmod 2}2^{(n,i)}\right]\\
&=\frac1{2n}\sum_{k|n}\left[\sum_{1\le i\le n}^{(n,i)=k \atop n/k=0\bmod 2}2^{k+1}
+\sum_{1\le i\le n}^{(n,i)=k \atop n/k=1\bmod 2}2^{k}\right]\\
&=\frac1{2n}\left[\sum_{k|n}^{n/k=0\bmod 2}2^{k+1}\sum_{1\le i\le n}^{(n,i)=k}1
+\sum_{k|n}^{n/k=1\bmod 2}2^{k}\sum_{1\le i\le n}^{(n,i)=k}1\right]\\
&=\frac1{2n}\left[\sum_{k|n}^{n/k=0\bmod 2}2^{k+1}\phi(n/k)
+\sum_{k|n}^{n/k=1\bmod 2}2^{k}\phi(n/k)\right]\\
&=\frac1{2n}\left[\sum_{d|n}^{d=0\bmod 2} 2^{n/d}\cdot2\phi(d)
+\sum_{d|n}^{d=1\bmod 2}2^{n/d}\cdot\phi(d)\right]\\
&=\frac1{2n}\sum_{d|n} 2^{n/d}\phi(2d),
\end{align}
$$
where the last equality follows from already mentioned in comments property:
$$
\phi(2d)=\begin{cases}
2\phi(d),& d=0\bmod 2\\
\phi(d),& d=1\bmod 2\\
\end{cases}.
$$